# Regex matching one instance of special character

Tags: regex

All, I have recently learnt a (very) basic understanding regex expressions to aid a variety of automations I am working within.

I am trying to match the first line (but not the second) of the below two text lines:

```
Nationwide > Karen Smith - Addleshaw Goddard 

Nationwide > Karen Smith - Addleshaw Goddard > Test 112
```

I am able to match the second line via:

```
.+\>.+\>
```

The text will change but the unique identifier is ">" which will only ever appear once in the first line which I am trying to match. Please can someone recommend how I would do this.

Thanks

Comment: You may use: `^[^>]*>[^>]*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex based on negated character class:

```
^[^>]*>[^>]*$
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^>]*`: match 0 or more of any character except `>`
- `>`: Match a single `>`
- `[^>]*`: match 0 or more of any character except `>`
- `$`: End